# Remove Y-Axis GridLines on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to remove all the y-axis grid lines except the outermost line?

In this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/abyrne85/g7vpq8ce/1/) for example, I'm trying to remove all lines (x-axis and y-axis) leaving just the outermost line and the data line, of course.

```
   $(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },

        title: {
            text: null,
            x: -80
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development',                 'Customer Support','Information Technology'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0
        },

        legend: {
            enabled:false
        },

        series: [{      
            data: [5, 3, 4, 3, 2],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Set `gridLineWidth`of xAxis to 0 to remove them.

**2.** Set `tickInterval` of yAxis larger than the maximum value in the data array so it will be the only grid line.

```
$(function () {
    var myData = [5, 3, 4, 3, 2],
        tickIntr = Math.max.apply(null, myData) + 1; //this is to set 
        //the tickInterval larger than the maximum value in data array

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
        },

        title: {
            text: null,
            x: -80
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 
                         'Customer Support','Information Technology'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0 //Remove xAxis lines
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: tickIntr //set yAxis tickInterval
        },

        legend: {
            enabled:false
        },

        series: [{      
            data: myData,
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7vpq8ce/2/

Answer (score 1):

Or use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner), see example: http://jsfiddle.net/g7vpq8ce/3/

```
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        tickPositioner: function(min, max){
            return [min, max];
        }
    },
```